# Unable to resolve "@react-native/assets-registry/registry" from "assets\image.png"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, tamagui

I used `npm create-expo-stack` to create the app. My tech stack includes **expo, expo router, and tamagui**.

I have this **metro.config.js**:

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;
```

I tried importing a png file to use in an Image component:

```
import { View, Image } from 'tamagui';
const logoImg = require('../assets/image.png');

export default function Page() {
  return (
     <View>
        <Image source={logoImg} />
     </View>
    )
}
```

**Problem**: when I try to run the app, an error occurs:
**Unable to resolve "@react-native/assets-registry/registry" from "assets\image.png"**

Note: I've tried importing Image from both react-native and tamagui imports.

Comment: Can you try the Image and View component from "react-native" for testing? I wonder if it has anything to do with tamagui.

Comment: I've tried using the Image from react-native but it does not work. I've decided to upload my files in a Supabase bucket instead of locally.